# Semantic UI, div child of column which grid class="ui grid celled padded" will not scroll - [Updated]

Tags: css, semantic-ui

This is plain Semantic UI and very lightweight CSS.

I am trying to put a list, which happens to be acting like a treeview, into a column and make it so that the list becomes scrollable if the height if its content exceeds the height of the parent column. I anticipate this being done with pure CSS. However, I can't seem to make it work. What am I doing wrong.

Here is a cut down version - sorry about the billions of divs but thats how Semantic UI list works and I needed enough to make a decent height in the list element.

Run the snippet to a new window then resize the window making it shorter by dragging the bottom edge upwards. You will see the bottom line of the grid moving to retrain its margin, and the cyan/blue border also moving up because its height=100% of parent and the parent height is being reduced.   When the cyan/blue border meets the magenta list element, we should get a vertical scroll bar somehow.

EDIT: It appears that the issue relates to

```
<div class="ui grid celled padded">
```

combined with

```
<div class="row">
```

After re-confirming I am not going mad and all one needs to do is set style @overflow-y: scroll@ on a plain div example, then returning to the demo below offline and chopping out all SUI bits then re-introducing, I came to this conclusion.

So re-coding it with plain

```
<div class="ui grid" style="height: 90%;">
```

and removing the row divs seems to be the way ahead. In my use case I don't specifically need the grid @celled padded@ options so no harm done.

However, in other cases wouldn't I want to be able to scroll over-long content in a fixed-height row ? Or am I overthinking this. Time for some coffee.

Original demo of the issue follows:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Treeview scaffolding</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />

  <style type='text/css'>
    
    .contentwrapper {
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    p {
      margin: 1em 0em;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class='body'>

  <div class="contentwrapper">

    <div class="ui grid celled padded" style="height: 100vh;">
      <div class="row" style="height: 10%;">
        <div id="info" class="sixteen wide column">
          <p>Info</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="stretched row" style="height: 90%">
        <!-- treeview, editor and props row -->
        <div id="nodes" class="four wide column">

          <div class="ui top attached large label" >Treeview</div>

          <div id="nodeListWrapper" class="" style="border: 1px solid cyan;">

            <div id="nodeList" class="" style="background-color: magenta; overflow-Y: auto;">
              <div class="ui list">
                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">Items 1 - 1 </div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Level 2 - 1</div>
                          <div class="list">
                            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                              <div class="content">
                                <div class="header">Level 3 - 1</div>
                                <div class="list">
                                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                    <div class="content">
                                      <div class="header">Level 4 - 1</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="list">
                                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                    <div class="content">
                                      <div class="header">Level 4 - 2</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Level 2 - 2</div>
                          <div class="list">
                            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                              <div class="content">
                                <div class="header">Etc </div>
                                <div class="list">
                                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                    <div class="content">
                                      <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="list">
                                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                    <div class="content">
                                      <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="list">
                                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                    <div class="content">
                                      <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Etc</div>
                          <div class="list">
                            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                              <div class="content">
                                <div class="header">Etc</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="list">
                            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                              <div class="content">
                                <div class="header">Etc</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui list" style='display: none;'>
              <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                <div class="content">
                  <div class="header">Etc</div>
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        <div class="list">
                          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                            <div class="content">
                              <div class="header">Etc</div>
                              <div class="list">
                                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                  <div class="content">
                                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="list">
                                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                  <div class="content">
                                    <div class="header">Etc
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        <div class="list">
                          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                            <div class="content">
                              <div class="header">Etc</div>
                              <div class="list">
                                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                  <div class="content">
                                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="list">
                                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                  <div class="content">
                                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="list">
                                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                                  <div class="content">
                                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="list">
                    <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        <div class="list">
                          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                            <div class="content">
                              <div class="header">Etc</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list">
                          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                            <div class="content">
                              <div class="header">Etc</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="display" class="ten wide column">
          <div class="ui top attached large label">Selected Info</div>

        </div>

        <div class="two wide column">
          <div class="ui top attached large label">Another column</div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>
<script src="../scripts/live.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this now

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">

<div class="ui top attached large label">Treeview</div>

<div id="nodeListWrapper" class="" style="border: 1px solid cyan;     height: 60vh;">

  <div id="nodeList" class="" style="background-color: magenta; overflow-Y: auto; height: 100%;">
    <div class="ui list">
      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="header">Items 1 - 1 </div>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="header">Level 2 - 1</div>
                <div class="list">
                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                      <div class="header">Level 3 - 1</div>
                      <div class="list">
                        <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                          <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Level 4 - 1</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="list">
                        <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                          <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Level 4 - 2</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="header">Level 2 - 2</div>
                <div class="list">
                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                      <div class="header">Etc </div>
                      <div class="list">
                        <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                          <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Etc</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="list">
                        <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                          <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Etc</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="list">
                        <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                          <div class="content">
                            <div class="header">Etc</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
              <div class="content">
                <div class="header">Etc</div>
                <div class="list">
                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                      <div class="header">Etc</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list">
                  <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                    <div class="content">
                      <div class="header">Etc</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui list" style='display: none;'>
    <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">Etc</div>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Etc</div>
              <div class="list">
                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Etc
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Etc</div>
              <div class="list">
                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list">
                      <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                        <div class="content">
                          <div class="header">Etc</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
          <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <div class="header">Etc</div>
              <div class="list">
                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="list">
                <div class="item"><i class="dot circle outline icon"></i>
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="header">Etc</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="display" class="ten wide column">
  <div class="ui top attached large label">Selected Info</div>

</div>

<div class="two wide column">
  <div class="ui top attached large label">Another column</div>



</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>



</body>
<script src="../scripts/live.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate - I'm not seeing where that is set currently in the demo?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat updated my answer check now please

Comment: Could you copy the snippet into your answer and make the edit ? I tried but it did did not make a scroll bar appear.

Comment: Thanks @Awais, but now it seems to be missing the grid & column structure that I need. It needs to be in that grid to illustrate this issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate please !

Comment: May be decreasing this height form `60vh` to `50vh` would work. `<div id="nodeListWrapper" class="" style="border: 1px solid cyan;     height: 60vh;">`